# Array.map not working correctly Javascript ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have filtered array of 2 users which have role of admin.

```
  const user = users.filter((user : any) => user.role === "admin")
```

After that I map them and I want to return single pair of these buttons

```
 {user.map((user : any) => {
       return  <div>
         <Link key={uuidv4()} to={`/profile/${user.id}`}>
           <button key={uuidv4()}>My Profile</button>
         </Link>
               <button onClick={() => {history.push('/adminPanel')}}>Admin Panel</button>
       </div>
    })}
```

But instead of 1 pair of buttons it returns 2 pair of buttons.
As i get its because I have 2 items in the array.

I want to return only one pair of buttons but I dont know which method to use,Please help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here exactly? If you want to always return one pair of buttons why are they returned in the map function?

Comment: I want to return only one pair of buttons but I cant think of method which would help me in this case

Comment: Why not just return them without the `map` method?

Comment: Use `.find` instead of `.filter`, it will stop searching after it found the first entry that has `role === 'admin'`. Besides that, it looks like your condition should be something different that will only allow a single entry to be returned afterwards, but that's another story I guess...